# Only one time welcome screen on android

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, intel-xdk

i am making an html5/javascript application at Intel XDK and i would like to add a welcome screen which will be displayed only once ever.

any help is welcome.
thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try storing a displayWelcomeScreen value in a cookie and check if its true.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cordova `localStorage` to save a value to detect first time or not.

Below is working sample:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>App</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Hello World</h1>

       <script src="cordova.js"></script>
       <script>
       function onDeviceReady() {
          welcomeScreen();
       }
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function welcomeScreen(){
            var welcome = window.localStorage.getItem("welcome");
            if(!welcome){
                window.localStorage.setItem("welcome", "1");
                alert("Welcome Message"); // replace with welcome screen display    
            }
        }


   </script>    
</body>
</html>
```